# powershell: delete specific line from x to x

Tags: powershell

I'm new in powershell and I absolutely dont get it ...

Just want to delete line 7 to 2500 of a text file. First 6 lines should be untouched.
With linux bash everything is so easy, just:
`sed -i '7,2500d' $file`

Did not find any solution for mighty powershell :-(

Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  That might help you get to the character limit without adding meaningless text.

Comment: Did you try to read the file and just work with the first six lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-Content` to read the contents of the file into a variable.  The variable can be indexed like a regular PowerShell array.  Get the parts of the array you need then pipe the variable into `Set-Content` to write back to the file.

```
$file = Get-Content test.log

$keep = $file[0..1] + $file[7..($file.Count - 1)]

$keep | Set-Content test.log
```

Using this as the contents of the file `test.log`:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
```

This script will output the following into test.log (overwriting the contents):

```
One
Two
Eight
Nine
```

In your case, you will want to use `$file[0..5] + $file[2500..($file.Count - 1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a series of lines in a text file, you could do something like this:

```
$fileIn  = 'D:\Test\File1.txt'
$fileOut = 'D:\Test\File2.txt'

$startRemove = 7
$endRemove   = 2500
$currentLine = 1

# needs .NET 4
$newText = foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($fileIn)) {
    if ($currentLine -lt $startRemove -or $currentLine -gt $endRemove) { $line}
    $currentLine++
}
$newText | Set-Content -Path $fileOut -Force
```

Or, if your version of .NET is below 4.0

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($fileIn)
$newText = while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
    if ($currentLine -lt $startRemove -or $currentLine -gt $endRemove) { $line }
    $currentLine++
}
$reader.Dispose()
$newText | Set-Content -Path $fileOut -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Select-object -index takes an array, so:

```
1..10 > file

(get-content file) | select -index (0..5) | set-content file
get-content file

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Or:

```
(cat file)[0..5] | set-content file
```